# In C# windows forms apps, is there a way to access buttons using integers?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array, where I store the numbers of buttons, but I want to use a check function:

```cs
void check()
{
    if (counter == 2)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        if ((buttons[0] == 1 && buttons[1] == 6) || (buttons[0] == 6 && buttons[1] == 1))
        {
            button1.BackgroundImage = null;
            button6.BackgroundImage = null;
        }
        buttons[0] = 0;
        buttons[1] = 0;
        counter = 0;
   }
}
```

So I was just wondering, is there a way, to set the background image without actually declaring like this?
For example like `buttons[0].buttons.BackGroundImage = null;`
Or is there an actual way to do this?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What are "the numbers of buttons"?  Did you mean to put the buttons themselves in the array?

Comment: Put them in an array `var buttons = new[] { button1, button2, button3 };`. But don't poll buttons. Use events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your `Button` objects in a list:

Define a member variable:

```
List<Button> buttonsList;
```

Then populate it with your actual `Button`s (the objects created by the designer):

```
buttonsList.Add(button1);
// ...
buttonsList.Add(button6);
// ...
```

Now the button number will be associated with the index in the list (in this specific example there will be an offset of 1 since the first `Button` is `button1`, not `button0`).
So you can directly change the `Button` properties by doing e.g. (for the first button):

```
buttonsList[0].BackGroundImage = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of buttons, filter the `Form.Controls` property

```
Button[] button = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
```

then you can do things like `button[0].Visibility = false;` and similarly.

Comment: Instead of `Where().Cast<T>()` you could use the `OfType<T>()` which does the job.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - correct.